# Python: Finding Relation between substrings of a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
Input_Str1 = " [This set contains Apple, **Banana**, Orange] [This set contains Grapes, Pineapple] [This set contains **Banana**,Peach,Mango,strawberry ]"
```

My output should print [1->3] indicating set 1 has a fruit banana that appears in set 3

```
Input_Str2 = " [This set contains **Apple**, Banana, **Orange**] [This set contains **Grapes**, Pineapple] [This set contains **Apple**,Peach,Mango,strawberry ] [This set contains Papaya, Guava, **Orange**, **Grapes**"]

Output: [1->3] [1->4] [2->4]
```

I was able to extract all the fruits in a set as items of a list but wasn't able to determine how to find relationships between items of different sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets; make a set from your lists of fruit items and use the `intersection` method against other sets built the same way to know if there is a relationship:

```
fruit_set_1  = set(fruit_list_1)
fruit_set_2  = set(fruit_list_2)
fruit_set_3  = set(fruit_list_3)

if len(fruit_set_1.intersection(fruit_set_2)):
  # relationship between 1 and 2
  ...
if len(fruit_set_1.intersection(fruit_set_3)):
  # relationship between 1 and 3
  ...
```

etc.